# Reordering context menu items in Foobar2000?

Tags: foobar2000

I read somewhere that context menu items in foobar2000 could not only be enabled/disabled, but also reordered in "Preferences: Context Menu".
Perhaps I'm missing something, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to reorder them; I tried dragging, right-clicking and several key combinations to no avail.

Am I missing something, or is this impossible (now)?

[image: Screenshot of the Preferences dialog]
(In this case I'd like to move the "Rating" item out of the Playback Statistics submenu.)

I'm using foobar2000 1.1.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

foobar2000 starting with v1 changed the context menu structure a bit and you cannot reorder the items anymore.

---

From the official website:

> ## [foobar2000 change log](http://www.foobar2000.org/changelog#section8)
>
> ### 1.0
>
> - New context menu structure - better out-of-the-box layout but less customizable.

Comment: Ouch. Not exactly what I wanted to hear, but I'll accept your answer in a few days if nothing else comes up.